# Поочередное появление и исчезновение элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт

```js
var $target = $('.good');
var hold = 200;


$.each($target,function(i,t){
     var $this = $(t);
     setTimeout(function(){ $this.show(); },i*hold);
});
```

```css
.good {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="good">Текст 1</div>
<div class="good">Текст 2</div>
<div class="good">Текст 3</div>
<div class="good">Текст 4</div>
```

Помогите его адаптировать так, чтоб при появлении одного элемента предыдущий исчезал и функция была зациклена, т.е бесконечно воспроизводилась

Comment: А вы с какой проблемой столкнулись, когда начали адаптировать его самостоятельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let $target = $('.good');
let hold = 500;
let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    if (index >=  $target.length)
      index = 0;
      
    $target.hide(); 
    $target.eq(index).show(); 
    index++;
  }, hold
);
```

```css
.good {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="good">Текст 1</div>
<div class="good">Текст 2</div>
<div class="good">Текст 3</div>
<div class="good">Текст 4</div>
```